# Why won't Oracle's Unified Audit Trail pick up the ALTER SESSION statement?

Tags: oracle, audit-trail

I have created a simple policy in Oracle 19c to audit when a user uses the "ALTER SESSION" privilege:

```
CREATE AUDIT POLICY ALT_SES_PLCY
  Privileges
    ALTER SESSION;

AUDIT POLICY ALT_SES_PLCY;
```

After creating and enabling the policy, I disconnect from the database, then reconnect. I then execute the following line:

```
ALTER SESSION SET CURRENT_SCHEMA = TEST_USER;
```

Then I check the audit trail:

```
SELECT * FROM UNIFIED_AUDIT_TRAIL
ORDER BY EVENT_TIMESTAMP_UTC DESC;
```

Yet there exist no record of the ALTER SESSION privilege being used. What gives? Why is this not being picked up?

Comment: I'm not sure that can be audited, unless you do something that requires the explicit privilege to do and isn't implicitly included in the `create session` privilege. Setting `current_schema` doesn't require the explicit privilege, but setting `sql_trace=true` would, for instance.